# $("div#myDiv").css("content") returns undefined in IE8

Tags: jquery

`$("div#myDiv").css("content")` returns *undefined* in IE8.
Works perfect in other browsers and IE6 & 7.

Comment: And what do the other browsers return?

Comment: Could there be an error in the html? Maybe something that the other browsers are ignoring but IE8 is tripping over?

Comment: I'm having the same problems.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ajkochanowicz/X8f6T

Answer (score 6):

Are you sure you shouldn't be doing:

```
$('div#myDiv').html()
```

or

```
$('div#myDiv').text()
```

That's how I would go about getting the "content" of a DIV.

Note, that if you are going after the content inserted by CSS, note that in IE8 you need to have a DOCTYPE ([reference](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_gen_content.asp)) for the document.

> Note: Internet Explorer 8 (and higher) supports the content property if a !DOCTYPE is specified.

Comment: Agreed. 'content' is a legitimate CSS property; even if browsers are returning the text of the element, I wouldn't depend on that.

Comment: Here's an example of it not working. Doctype is specified. http://jsfiddle.net/ajkochanowicz/X8f6T/

Answer (score 5):

The `content` property is only supposed to be used with `:before` or `:after` pseudoelements to generate content:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#content

What you are seeing is not the `content` css property actually doing anything. You will notice in your fiddle that the "hello world" text **is not rendered**. What Chrome/Firefox/other browsers are returning is simply the computed value of a CSS class that happens to accept an arbitrary string. The way each browser returns such a value is not part of the spec, since this is not how it's intended to be used. So all bets are off and you shouldn't "expect" anything. It would be perfectly reasonable for a browser to simply return nothing, since this isn't a valid use, making it an illegal style that could be ignored.

If you actually add `:before` or `:after` to the style definition, you'll see it renders "hello world":

http://jsfiddle.net/jamietre/X8f6T/42/

You'll also see that you can't retrieve the value of "content" any more, either by looking at computed CSS or with `.text()`, because there's no way to target it using a selector. "content" renders text as if it were a style - it does not create text nodes. You were only accessing the value of a style inherited from the style sheet before; not the value of something in the DOM.

The only way you could reliably access that information would be by inspecting the actual style sheet:

http://jsfiddle.net/jamietre/X8f6T/45/

This happens to grab that style and should work in any browser:

```
document.styleSheets[document.styleSheets.length-1].rules[0].style.content
```

Of course to do this in an unknown context, you'd need to iterate through all the stylesheets & styles looking for `content` properties.

Quirks mode says that `content` may work in some browsers without `:before` or `:after`. This is extremely outdated information, but I mention it to reinforce that you're trying to understand why things aren't consistent when using something in an illegal way. There's no reason, other than the whim of some programmer, nor is it a bug, since it's not part of any spec.

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/content.html

The bottom line is, this script is using `content` in a nonstandard way. So the fact that it doesn't work in IE isn't so much a problem, rather, it's an anomaly that it *does* work in the way that OP thinks it should anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Found an unusual fix. For some reason, using a fake css property IE8 is suddenly able to get *that*.

http://jsfiddle.net/X8f6T/25/

In this case, I just used "ie8" as the css property so I remember what it's for.

Disclaimer: this is 100% a hack.